# In DevExpress xtra reports, I would like to increase height of table dynamically

Tags: devexpress, runtime, tabular, xtrareport

In devexpress report, I have two tables. Based on content `T2` table height increases, based on `T1` height should be set.

I tried to set height in `BeforePrint`, `AfterPrint`, `SizeChanged`, `TextChanged` events of `T2` and also `DataSourceChanged` event of report, as follows, added image for reference.

```cs
T1.HeightF = T2.HeightF;
```

or

```cs
T1.SizeF = new SizeF(T1.WidthF, T2.HeightF);
```

[image: Example]

But above ways didn't work out.
Any idea how to set height of table dynamically?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [`XRControl.AnchorVertical`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRControl_AnchorVerticaltopic) property of your table to [`VerticalAnchorStyles.Both`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraReportsUIVerticalAnchorStylesEnumtopic) value, so your table will be always attached to sides of its container.

```cs
xrTable1.AnchorVertical = VerticalAnchorStyles.Both;
```

Here is example:

```cs
var source = new List<Tuple<string>>()
{
    new Tuple<string>("Text"),
    new Tuple<string>("Some\ntext"),
    new Tuple<string>("Some long long\nlong long long\nlong long long text.")
};

var cell = new XRTableCell();
cell.Text = "Just table";

var someCell = new XRTableCell();
someCell.Text = "Some text";

var anotherCell = new XRTableCell();
anotherCell.Text = "Another cell text";

var contentCell = new XRTableCell();
contentCell.DataBindings.Add(new XRBinding("Text", null, "Item1"));
contentCell.Multiline = true;

var anotherContentCell = new XRTableCell();
anotherContentCell.Text = "Content table";

var row = new XRTableRow();
row.Cells.AddRange(new[] { cell, someCell, anotherCell });

var contentRow = new XRTableRow();
contentRow.Cells.AddRange(new[] { contentCell, anotherContentCell });

var table = new XRTable();
table.Rows.Add(row);
table.Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.All;
table.AnchorVertical = VerticalAnchorStyles.Both;

var contentTable = new XRTable();
contentTable.Rows.Add(contentRow);
contentTable.Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.All;
contentTable.LeftF = 350F;

var panel = new XRPanel();
panel.HeightF = contentTable.HeightF = table.HeightF = 15F;
panel.WidthF = 650F;
panel.Controls.AddRange(new[] { table, contentTable });            

var detail = new DetailBand();
detail.HeightF = 30F;
detail.Controls.Add(panel);

var report = new XtraReport();
report.Bands.Add(detail);
report.DataSource = source;

report.ShowRibbonPreview();
```

Here is result of example:

[image: Result]

Comment: nempoBu4 :
I have added the above picture. You  can see the borders.

Comment: @PrasannaKottapalli It's unclear what's wrong with your tables, because there are no code in your question. I have added code to my answer, can you test this code?

Comment: if you can see the image, 1st table border not coming up till the end

Comment: @PrasannaKottapalli I see the image, but I don't see your code. Have you tried my example?

Comment: Yeah it worked with 
** tbl1.AnchorVertical = VerticalAnchorStyles.Both; **

The only issue here is, left side table getting more gaps in between the  cells.

Comment: @PrasannaKottapalli You can add your tables into one `XRPanel` container with the same `HeightF` property to make sure that gaps will be the same. I have changed the code in my answer. Consider the same `HeightF` for tables and panel: `panel.HeightF = contentTable.HeightF = table.HeightF = 15F;`.